# Facing 'list' object has no attribute 'find' error while parsing all docuemnts inside a collection

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pymongo

Hi I have a database name:Tmobile and it has a collection with two files Mynew and 30dc..

See image

[image: Database image]

Now i am trying to loop through the files and print any element /file from it.

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from unittest.mock import inplace
from pymongo import MongoClient
from idlelib.rpc import response_queue
from pandas import DataFrame

connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db=connection.Tmobile
collection=db.Collections
#print(collection)
for collection1 in collection.find():
    print(collection1)
```

But when i try this i get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\esrilka\eclipse-workspace\My First PyDev Project\dbsample.py", line 13, in <module>
['30dc6d110c7a0d3d371177ac0a3624bc_1', 'Mynew']
    for collection in collection.find():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve my calling a method that doesn't exist?

Comment: hi i would like to load/read the json file present inside the collection.can i know how to achieve that

Comment: What is `collection.find()`? Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: I just tried that..in that way.Not sure if its correc.Can you suggest how to acheive that

Comment: With `db.collection_name` you get the mongodb collection with the collection_name, where as with `db.collection_names` you get a list of all collection names. So, you know the difference, the list will not have a find method. You may just try using `db.Collections` that should return you the collection with the name `Collections` from your example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985684/mongodb-show-all-contents-from-all-collections

Comment: Yes, your collection_name is `Collections`, so you need to use `collection=db.Collections` in stead of `collection=db.collection_names(include_system_collections=False)`

Comment: i chnaged it but what i get is "Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'Tmobile'), 'Collections')"

Comment: Bu ti am trying to print the elements inside the collections

Comment: What is your output with the second print statement in for loop? Do you get any error?

Comment: Dint get any output for second print statement.Its blank

Comment: Hope you undertand my question.i would like to print the complete json say "Mynew" which is present inside Collection.However i dont want to mention the name,it should be kind of iterative

Comment: It should print all documents inside `Collections`, I am not sure what is the issue. Please update your edits to the post here, so that I can see what is wrong

Comment: Updated the code..please check

Comment: OK, Please `print(collection.count())` before the for loop and see what you get.

Comment: I get the output as 0

Comment: :), ha, no reason why the second print statement prints empty,  that means you dont have the json documents as claimed in your example. Go, check your database..

Comment: did you check the mongo database with mongo console?

Comment: Hi Finally,got the result with the below code

Comment: connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db=connection.Tmobile
collection=db.TmobileCollection
temp_data=pd.DataFrame()


for item in collection.find():
    temp_creationdate =pd.DataFrame({"creation-date": [item["creation-date"]]})